# Issues creating podspec

Tags: cocoapods

So I am trying to create a podspec in an attempt to push something to cocoapods so everyone can use it.

However when I create my podspec and run

> pod spec lint

I get these errors

> -> VideoRow (1.0.0)
>       - ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
>       - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
>       - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
>       - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
>       - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'App')

I followed an online tutorial up until this point and his validated perfectly but mines didn't

```
    Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "VideoRow"
  spec.version      = "1.0.0"
  spec.summary      = "Eureka row that allows users to select videos"
  spec.description  = "This framework is an add on to the many rows that encompass the Eureka Community. This row will allow users to select videos from there media library to potentially export to some backend service."
  spec.homepage     = "https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/VideoRow"
  spec.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  spec.author       = { "aaaa" => "a.b@rowan.edu" }
  spec.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/Apples'
  spec.platform    = :ios, "9.1"
  spec.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/Apples/AppleRow.git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
  spec.source_files  = 'VideoRow'
  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.dependency "Eureka"
  spec.dependency "TLPhotoPicker"
  spec.swift_version = '4.2'
end
```

This is what my podspec currently looks like. Does anyone notice what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is accurate: `The source_files pattern did not match any file.`

Likely you want something like: `spec.source_files  = 'VideoRow/**/*.[mh]'`

More details in the [podspec docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files).